# Form won't save, and no validation errors are showing on redirect. Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, simple-form

My job applications form object is refusing to insert into the database, even though the parameters are correct and no errors are being appended to the error log. I have a user model, job model and job_application model. The user model is unable to save job_applications to the job model. How can I correctly setup the form to insert without failure?

console error

```
Started POST "/job_applications" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-02-05 16:02:44 -0500
Processing by JobApplicationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"CEUd0b1IiA1iNUJ06BIycpiECrz2Q8W9Ol0Y/BDUC1ctWKjAn5/EoW8s157NAGiKFH+CZ4bZBzWAVRJvleyLSw==", "job_application"=>{"job_id"=>"1", "user_first_name"=>"James", "user_last_name"=>"Goober", "user_contact_time"=>"PM", "user_resume_link"=>"4"}, "commit"=>"Submit Application"}
  User Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  BEGIN
  Job Load (7.0ms)  SELECT  "jobs".* FROM "jobs" WHERE "jobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendering job_applications/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Resume Load (3.0ms)  SELECT "resumes".* FROM "resumes" WHERE "resumes"."user_id" = $1 ORDER BY "resumes"."title" ASC  [["user_id", 1]]
  Rendered job_applications/_form.html.erb (792.8ms)
```

job application _form partial

```
<%= simple_form_for([@job_application]) do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :job_id %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-4">
        <label for="user-first-name">First Name</label>
        <%= f.input :user_first_name, class: 'form-control', required: true, label: false %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-4">
        <label for="user-last-name">Last Name</label>
        <%= f.input :user_last_name, class: 'form-control', required: true, label: false %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-3">
        <label for="user-contact-time">Contact Time</label>
        <%= f.input :user_contact_time, collection: %w(AM PM), class: 'form-control', required: true, label: false, prompt: 'Daytime or Evening' %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-4">
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
          <label for="user-resume-link"><%= fa_icon 'clone' %> Resume Repository</label>
        <%= f.input :user_resume_link, collection: current_user.resumes.order(:title), prompt: "Select your Resume", label: false %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-4">
        <%= f.button :submit, 'Submit Application', class: 'btn btn-blue form-control' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

job_application.rb

```
class JobApplication < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :employer
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :job
  delegate :resume, to: :user
  validates :user_first_name, presence: true, uniqueness: false, length: {maximum: 50}, format: {with: /\A[a-zA-Z]+(?: [a-zA-Z]+)?\z/}
  validates :user_last_name, presence: true, uniqueness: false, length: {maximum: 50}, format: {with: /\A[a-zA-Z]+(?: [a-zA-Z]+)?\z/}
  validates :user_resume_link, presence: true
  validates :user_contact_time, presence: true
end
```

job.rb

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
has_many :job_applications, dependent: destory
# accepts_nested_attributes_for :job_applications, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

job_applications_controller

```
class JobApplicationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_job_application, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:create, :new, :update, :destroy, :edit]

  # GET /job_applications/1
  # GET /job_applications/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /job_applications/new
  def new
    @job_application = JobApplication.new
  end

  # GET /job_applications/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /job_applications
  # POST /job_applications.json
  def create
    @job_application = current_user.job_applications.build(job_application_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @job_application.save
        format.html { redirect_to @job_application, notice: 'Job application was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @job_application }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @job_application.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /job_applications/1
  # PATCH/PUT /job_applications/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @job_application.update(job_application_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @job_application, notice: 'Job application was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @job_application }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @job_application.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /job_applications/1
  # DELETE /job_applications/1.json
  def destroy
    @job_application.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to job_applications_url, notice: 'Job application was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_job_application
      @job_application = JobApplication.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def job_application_params
      params.require(:job_application).permit(:user_first_name, :user_last_name, :user_contact_time, :user_resume_link, :employer_id, :job_id, resumes_attributes: [:id, :title, :_destroy])
    end
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
has_many :job_applications, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :jobs, :through => :job_applications
end
```

Comment: You have a spelling mistake in the Job model `dependent: destory`

Comment: "ROLLBACK" in the logs suggest to me a validation error for `@job_application`. Try temporarily use `@job_application.save!` instead of `@job_application.save` inside your `def create` action. Once you determined the problem, fix the corresponding validation code, then make sure to revert back to `.save`

Comment: Can you confirm that your `def job_application_params` is correct? You have a lot of fields for user/resume... but... are they actual columns on the job-application table or are you trying to munge them into the relationships? (because that won't work and you'll need proper nested fields/attributes for that). Can you give us the actual error message you get? (can you show us more of the console output?) what happens when you try to create one via the console? what else have you tried? etc :)

Comment: does job with id=1 belong to user with =1? It looks like the controller is rolling back because of the `before_action`

Comment: It was an incorrect relationship model that led to the error. I found out by using Jay-Ar Polidario's approach. save! showed that the employer was being added for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your forms generates inputs like

```
<input type="text" name="job_application[user-first-name]">
```

And NOT like that

```
<input type="text" name="user-first-name">
```

In 2nd case you would need to rewrite form parameters as

```
   def job_application_params
      params.permit(:user_first_name, :user_last_name, :user_contact_time, :user_resume_link, :employer_id, :job_id, resumes_attributes: [:id, :title, :_destroy])
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

The relationship between the user model, job model and application model were setup incorrectly. The job_application belongs to the user, but the job itself belongs to the employer. The job_application does not belong to the employer. But, it still can access it through the job itself.

job_application.rb

```
class JobApplication < ApplicationRecord
  # belongs_to :employer removing this line, eliminated the error.
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :job
  delegate :resume, to: :user
  validates :user_first_name, presence: true, uniqueness: false, length: {maximum: 50}, format: {with: /\A[a-zA-Z]+(?: [a-zA-Z]+)?\z/}
  validates :user_last_name, presence: true, uniqueness: false, length: {maximum: 50}, format: {with: /\A[a-zA-Z]+(?: [a-zA-Z]+)?\z/}
  validates :user_resume_link, presence: true
  validates :user_contact_time, presence: true
end
```